# Generating SCTP traffic in linux?

Tags: linux, sctp

I want to simulate a network with two multihoomed SCTP hosts.

After I have enabled SCTP in my Linux Kernel, what would be the next step towards setting up a network? Is this possible to do so using only one computer with virtual machines? What programs should I use for generating SCTP traffic?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example you can code your own SCTP app.

First you need to check if your installation supports SCTP protocol:

```
# checksctp 
SCTP supported
```

If not, you can install it depending on your distribution, example:

```
# apt-get install libsctp-dev
```

Here is small kick in for you, how to do it in C:

Include SCTP library like:

```
#include <netinet/sctp.h>
```

and you need to attach it during compiling via `-lsctp`:

```
gcc -Wall server.c -lsctp -o server
```

check man pages of sctp, and play with `sctp_sendmsg()` and `sctp_recvmsg()` fucntions to use needed SCTP features.

And yes, it's fine to work with virtual machines.

Good luck

Comment: The `gcc` command needs to be `gcc -Wall server.c -lsctp -o server` (the order of arguments to `gcc` matters a lot)